# Starting Activity Indicator while Running a database download in a background thread

Tags: swift2, grand-central-dispatch

I am running a database download in a background thread. The threads work fine and I execute group wait before continuing.

The problem I have is that I need to start an activity indicator and it seems that due to the group_wait it gets blocked.

Is there a way to run such heavy process, ensure that all threads get completed while allowing the activity indicator to run?

I start the activity indicator with (I also tried starting the indicator w/o the dispatch_async):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  activityIndicator.startAnimating()
})
```

After which, I start the thread group:

```
let group: dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create()

let queue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //also tried QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND

 while iter > 0 {

     iter--

     dispatch_group_enter(group)

     dispatch_group_async(group, queue, {

        do {

           print("in queue \(iter)")

           temp += try query.findObjects()

           query.skip += query.limit

        } catch let error as NSError {

          print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")              
     }

    dispatch_group_leave(group)

   })

 }

// Wait for all threads to finish and proceed
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am using Parse, I have modified the code as follows (psuedo code for simplicity):

```
trigger the activity indicator with startAnimating()

call the function that hits Parse

set an observer in the Parse class on an int to trigger an action when the value reaches 0

get count of new objects in Parse

calculate how many loop iterations I need to pull all the data (using max objects per query = 1000 which is Parse max)

while iterations > 0 {
  create a Parse query object
  set the query skip value
  use query.findObjectsInBackroundWithBlock ({
     pull objects and add to a temp array
     observer--
  )}

  iterations--
}

When the observer hits 0, trigger a delegate to return to the caller
```

Works like a charm.